# What is the purpose of the wget startup file option "add-hostdir"?

Tags: backup, wget

The [wget 1 man pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Syntax) describe the option "add-hostdir" as follows:

```
Enable/disable host-prefixed file names. ‘-nH’ disables it.
```

Unfortunately, I am too ignorant to understand this.
Since "-nH" disables it, it must have something to do with [spanning hosts](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Spanning-Hosts), but it isn't described there either.

Can someone explain what it does?

I am using wget 1.19.1

Answer (score 0):

Consider simple example

```
wget -r http://www.example.com
```

create directory `www.example.com` and place `index.html` inside it

```
wget -r -nH http://www.example.com
```

just places `index.html` in current working directory, that is you have one level less (top one) of catalog hierarchy when using `-nH`.

Speaking simply with `-nH` will not create catalog for each domain.

Comment: It's clear what -nH does.  My question is, what does  "add-hostdir" do?

Comment: @RB add-hostdir does make domain to be first element of path to each element